# Cypress Typescript: How do I get a certain value from dataTable?

Tags: typescript, datatables, cucumber, cypress

I have this data table, with a list of cause (state) and effect (message) that I want to check in the scenario.

```
Given user inputs "<state>" and sees "<message>" message
        | state       | message      |
        | Deactivated | error        |
        | Taken       | error        |
        | Unused      | confirmation |
```

I tried to use this script but it's just executing all below `state` instead of also executing `message` actions.

```
Given(‘user inputs {string} and sees {string} message’, (dataTable: DataTable) => {

dataTable.hashes().forEach(elem =>{
        if(elem.state == 'Deactivated') {
            <DeactivatedAction>
        } else if(elem.state == 'Taken') {
            <TakenAction>
        } else if(elem.state == 'Unused') {
            <UnusedAction>
        } else {
            throw new Error("No state defined")
        } 
    })

dataTable.hashes().forEach(elem =>{
        if(elem.message == 'error') {
            <errorAction>
        } else if(elem.message == 'confirmation') {
            <confirmationAction>
        } else {
            throw new Error("No state defined")
        } 
    })
}
```

The same thing happens when I change `.forEach()` to `.map()`. :/

Comment: It works fine for me - please give more details about the error you have.

Comment: Does it do <DeactivatedAction> then <errorAction> @user16695029? Mine doesn't do it. It's the same script I have :/

Comment: Yes. What exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the 2nd loop to access "message", if so it looks more like a typo - you reference `elem.state` instead of `elem.message`.

```js
dataTable.hashes().forEach(elem => {
  if (elem.message === 'error') {
    <errorAction>
  } else if (elem.message === 'confirmation') {
    <confirmationAction>
  } else {
    throw new Error("No state defined")
  } 
})
```

Comment: Hello @Yolandi sorry for the typo. I updated the script above. Yes it should be elem.message. Do we have a way to choose which column and row we want in a datatable?

Comment: Ok, I thought that was too easy. So, can you give details on the "hidden" bits - the  `dataTable.hashes()` part looks key, but no details shown.

Comment: I didn't get it @Yolandi sorry could you please elaborate?

Comment: There's not enough details on the `dataTable` object (or is it a class?) or the `.hashes()` method. Since they provide the array of `elem`, it's not possible to answer your question without those details.

Comment: I've updated the script with the Gherkin syntax used @Yolandi

Comment: I don't see how that helps - as I said the  `.hashes()` method is key. Why don't you post the whole Datable class?

Comment: I got it from here @Yolandi https://minium.vilt.io/docs/core/api/cucumber/

Comment: Do you mean [cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/data_table.ts](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/cb6f7882870a0be4bffe1de5db580d058f7a15b9/lib/data_table.ts)? That other link does not give any information about how it works with the test.

Answer (score 1):

Technically if you combine the loops, both sections should work

```js
dataTable.hashes().forEach(elem => {
  if (elem.state == 'Deactivated') {
    <DeactivatedAction>
  } else if (elem.state == 'Taken') {
    <TakenAction>
  } else if (elem.state == 'Unused') {
    <UnusedAction>
  } else {
    throw new Error("No state defined")
  } 

  if(elem.message == 'error') {
    <errorAction>
  } else if(elem.message == 'confirmation') {
    <confirmationAction>
  } else {
    throw new Error("No state defined")
  } 
})
```

But that's a bit obvious. It feels like there must be some sort of connection between state and message in the row,

```js
function doMessage(message) {
  if(message == 'error') {
    <errorAction>
  } else if(message == 'confirmation') {
    <confirmationAction>
  } else {
    throw new Error("No state defined")
  } 
}

dataTable.hashes().forEach(elem => {
  if (elem.state == 'Deactivated') {
    <DeactivatedAction>
    cy.then(() => doMessage(elem.message))

  } else if (elem.state == 'Taken') {
    <TakenAction>
    cy.then(() => doMessage(elem.message))

  } else if (elem.state == 'Unused') {
    <UnusedAction>
    cy.then(() => doMessage(elem.message))

  } else {
    throw new Error("No state defined")
  } 
})
```